# rails 3 - belongs_to :uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, belongs-to, unique

I want do a one-to-one relationship, unique.

So I have in a model this association and validation

belongs_to :bicycle
validates :bicycle, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

And give me this error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "FROM": syntax error: SELECT      FROM       "transactions"  WHERE     ("transactions"."bicycle" IS NULL) AND ("transactions"."bicycle" IS NULL) LIMIT 1

I don't know why the query is not well constructed... It is a bug of rails3?

Comment: this may not be related to the validates... could you post the code that actually generates the sql?

Answer (score 6):

You should probably validate the attribute and not the association. The attribute in this case would be bicycle_id. So if you change it to:

```
validates :bicycle_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

that should work.

Comment: no... you are write.. must be bicycle_id instead of bicycle... BUT continues the same error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "FROM": syntax error: SELECT FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions"."bicycle_id" IS NULL) AND ("transactions"."bicycle_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1